# HttpContent gets disposed between try and catch

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, dotnet-httpclient, idisposable

I'm performing a simple GET request to a ASP.NET Core Web API, I created, within Xamarin.Forms 4.8. For this I'm using the following code:

```
public async Task<Result<bool>> GetSomeResult()
{
    var client = service.Client;

    HttpResponseMessage response = null;

    try
    {
        response = await client.GetAsync(new UriHelper(endpoint, "someEndpoint")).ConfigureAwait(false);

        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(); // will throw a exception on a non-success status code

        return await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<bool>().ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (response?.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)
        {
            // !!! The error occurs in the next line !!!
            SomeErrorClass id = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<SomeErrorClass>().ConfigureAwait(false);
            return new Result<bool>(SomeErrorClass.ToString());
        }

        return new Result<bool>(ex);
    }
}
```

The `service` is a singleton that's being injected into the constructor (via DryIoc) of the surrounding class. This `service` is a wrapper around a `HttpClient` instance and does nothing more than providing a facility to configure the `HttpClient` (as well as disposing and replacing the instance when its configuration has been chaned). So after configuration the same `HttpClient` instance will be returned whenever `service.Client` is used. The code is something like this:

```
public class ServiceConnection
{
    private const string Localhost = "https://127.0.0.1";

    private readonly PreferenceService preferences;
    private readonly IHttpClientHandlerProvider handlerProvider;

    public HttpClient Client { get; private set; }

    public ServiceConnection(PreferenceService preferences, IHttpClientHandlerProvider handlerProvider)
    {
        this.preferences = preferences;
        this.handlerProvider = handlerProvider;

        Client = CreateClient();
    }

    private HttpClient CreateClient()
    {
        var handler = new TimeoutHandler()
        {
            DefaultTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10),
            InnerHandler = handlerProvider?.GetHandler(opt =>
            {
                opt.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = HttpClientHandler.DangerousAcceptAnyServerCertificateValidator;
                opt.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                opt.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
            })
        };

        Uri.TryCreate($"{preferences.Server ?? Localhost}/api/", UriKind.Absolute, out var baseAddress);

        var client = new HttpClient(handler, true)
        {
            BaseAddress = baseAddress,
            Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20),
        };

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(CustomHttpHeaders.DeviceId, preferences.UUID);

        return client;
    }

    public void RefreshConnection()
    {
        Client?.Dispose();
        Client = CreateClient();
    }
}
```

The problem is the line in which I try to read the `HttpContent` from the `HttpResponseMessage`. Whenever I call it I get a `System.ObjectDisposedException`saying 'Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'System.Net.Http.StreamContent'.'.

I already tried setting the `disposeHandler` parameter of the `HttpClient` to `true` and `false` since I've seen some people on the internet suggesting that that'll fix the issue, but no luck for me so far.

Comment: The content or the *stream*? Your code already read everything from the network stream so it's impossible to read from it again. A NetworkStream is controlled by the *server* and can't just restart

Comment: Trying to read and deserialize the same content twice, as two different classes, would be wasteful even if it was possible. The content only needs to be read once. After that, the actual contents can be deserialized using any deserializer you want

Comment: It would be better (and a lot faster) to not throw at all too. Instead of calling `EnsureSuccessStatusCode()`, check the status of the response. Right now you're using exceptions for flow control, when an `if` would work

Comment: I edited the code to clarify that `EnsureSuccessStatusCode` will throw an exception before `response.Content.Read...` is called a first time. And yes, it is correct that I could use `response.IsSuccessStatusCode` instead of throwing an exception and than working with it, but this does not cause the problem, that I can't read the content within the catch.

Comment: That's the actual problem. Don't use exceptions for flow control.

Comment: BTW you haven't posted the exception, only a description of it. Post the *full exception text*. Not just the message, post the full output of `Exception.ToString()`. This includes the stack trace that shows what led to the exception

Comment: Using exceptions for flow control is ugly, I know. But I don't think it's the actual cause for the `StreamContent` being disposed between try and catch, is it?

Comment: *Post the full exception text*. It's obvious the Content isn't disposed, something else is. I'm pretty sure it's the stream, but the question doesn't show what's actually disposed.

Comment: From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage.ensuresuccessstatuscode?view=net-5.0)  *"In .NET Framework and .NET Core 2.2 and earlier versions, if the Content is not null, this method will also call Dispose to free managed and unmanaged resources."*

Comment: BTW [EnsureStatusCode disposes when it throws](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/24845). So yes, the exception is the reason

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Ah, okay, **that** helps ('EnsureStatusCode disposes when it throws'). Please add this to your answer so I could mark it as correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem isn't disposal. There are two problems here, one causing the other:

1. Exceptions are used for flow control. Instead of throwing on failure, you could check the response's status code
2. Before .NET Core 3, [EnsureStatusCode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage.ensuresuccessstatuscode?view=net-5.0#remarks) closes the stream.

The root cause is the use of exceptions for flow control.

This can be solved by fixing the first problem, which would also improve performance a *lot*. Throwing exceptions is expensive, several orders of magnitude more expensive than an `if`. As in 100-1000x times faster :

```
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    var value=await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<bool>();
    return value; //Should this be `new Result(value) ??
}
else if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)
{
    var id = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<SomeErrorClass>();
    return new Result<bool>(SomeErrorClass.ToString());
}
else
{
    var reason=$"{response.StatusCode}:{response.ReasonPhrase}";
    return new Result<bool>(reason);
}
```

Throwing would obfuscate the response phrase too, which would make troubleshooting a lot harder

Comment: There sadly seems to be no word about .NET Standard/Xamarin.Forms/Xamarin.Android (which I am using here) but I would just assume that the disposing is done there, too.